# compare value from an array in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts-tags

I have an array of String in java. I want to check if a value is present in this array using struts tags. The case of the value should be ignored.

Not sure how to do that. I have written following code.

sharedListEligible is the Java String array here which contains 2 values "US" and "Canada"

```
     <s:if test="%{myValue in sharedListEligible}">                     

       <span class="caret"></span>

     </s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

`%{}` should be put (if necessary) around all the statement, not in the middle. Iterate through the list and add if condition.

For Strings you should use `.equals`, `.equalsIgnoreCase`, `.contains`, `.indexOf` etc... Not `==`.

Please see: https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html

Change to this:

```
<s:iterator value="sharedListEligible" var="sharedEligibleVal" status="currentRecord"> 
   <s:if test="%{#sharedEligibleVal.equalsIgnoreCase(myValue)}">
   </s:if>
```